# Spring, Hibernate: DAO-Class: Using always the same object?

Tags: hibernate, spring, singleton, dao

Im working with Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.6 on developing a webapplication.

I have a DAO-Class and I created in a xml-file ONE bean (named "dao1") for it. Every class which needs to access the database get this instace injected. It is ALWAYS the same dao-object (scope=singleton)

Now I wonder if this is a recommended way of using a DAO. Would it be better to inject always different instances in other classes and if yes, why?
Would it also be better to split the DAO in different classes containing always some dao-methods, maybe specific for one table?

are there any disadvantages when I use the structure I mentioned?

thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

With Hibernate / JPA, the dao requires a fresh session/entity manager. But spring handles that by injecting a proxy which locates the fresh session each time. So having a `singleton` DAO is the proper way to go.

To clarify - if you DAO does not hold any state (i.e. doesn't have instance fields) apart from injected dependencies, then it can safely be singleton. Otherwise - not.

Comment: I believed this, but in the spring forum I found another answer, so Im not sure anymore(?): http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?107243-dao-%28plain-hibernate%29-singleton&highlight=

Comment: the answer there is the same as mine - if you don't keep any state in the dao, it can be singleton. The only stateful thing is the entity manager, but spring takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb when working with injections is to ask yourself.

> Are there any state in this component/bean/object ?

If there are state that has to be handled per call or whatever, you need to alter the scope or lifecycle. If not, then you should configure it as singleton.

And generally in a DAO class, there are no state. Or shouldn't be. The state should be in the persistence target (the database).

Therefore it's a pretty safe guess to say that you are perfectly fine configuring it as Singleton in this case.

Comment: daos usually need at least a connection, which differs for different users, so it is some sort of state

Comment: Connections [to a database] is usually the same for all users. At least in web applications.

Comment: sorry, by "users" I meant "threads". Usually Each thread has a different connection.